# Chrome pdf font size differences with local Chrome & Chromium in Docker (Linux)

Tags: google-chrome, docker, pdf-generation, chromium, puppeteer

I'm generating pdf's on a web server with puppeteer in Chrome.

The problem:
Font sizes differ slightly (2-5pixels depending on the font size) between my local Chrome (Mac) and Chromium being run inside the docker container (Linux). No other css attributes or the print @page margins seem to be affected, only the font-size is bigger in the docker container. The font is also being correctly embedded.

The pdf's I'm creating have to be pixel perfect (space is very limited), so this throws of the pagination... Any other ideas in addition to what I've tried already?

- Font-sizes in px or cm
- Make sure the font's are embedded with the correct [Docker file config](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md)

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Font-size is bigger on Chromium linux than macOS, so it prints differently! If someone has a solution, please...

Comment: Puppeteer peeps can't help with the pdf rendering bugging out, so if you're running into this, I recommend posting a small reproducible example to the Chromium devs: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines
(I haven't yet, just learned to live with it and setting the line-height to everything helps keeping the vertical height in check.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only half the solution for fixing the vertical size differences:

Set a numerical line-height (e.g. `line-height: 1`) in the body (`normal` is not enough), and then set line-heights to all other text elements.

This will work to keep the vertical heights identical for single line elements in local Chrome & docker Chromium. But if you have text flowing on multiple lines, the bigger font-size in docker Chromium can cause the text to take up additional rows. My bad workaround: make the font-size a bit smaller :(

Comment: Thanks for the line heights tip! Will try it. Like you I had to resort using a smaller font-size :(

Comment: How about setting the font-size of the <html>-tag to 20px and the scale of the PDF to 0.6? You will need relative font-sizes for the whole page to make it work.